# Creating numpy array with grid cell area in GDAL/rasterio?

Tags: gdal, numpy, rasterio

I want to create a numpy array of size 2160 * 4320 with each grid cell containing the size of a 5' grid cell on earth.

Is there a python library or function to do this?

I am using GDAL and rasterio.

Comment: I suspect that there are many.  Are you already using ArcPy or any other common Python libraries for GIS?

Comment: @PolyGeo, I am not using ArcPy, can use gdal or rasterio though.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand what you are asking...do you need to load  data into this numpy array or are you just trying to create it? Numpy by itself has no sense of spatial information, so creating a 2160x4320 array is simply that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy doesn't support any spatial info. You can use **pyshp** library for the same. https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp

```
import shapefile as shp
import math

minx,maxx,miny,maxy = xxxxx, xxxxx, xxxxx, xxxxx (specify the extents)
dx = xx (size of grid)
dy = xx (size of grid)

nx = int(math.ceil(abs(maxx - minx)/dx))
ny = int(math.ceil(abs(maxy - miny)/dy))

w = shp.Writer(shp.POLYGON)
w.autoBalance = 1
w.field("ID")
id=0

for i in range(ny):
    for j in range(nx):
        id+=1
        vertices = []
        parts = []
        vertices.append([min(minx+dx*j,maxx),max(maxy-dy*i,miny)])
        vertices.append([min(minx+dx*(j+1),maxx),max(maxy-dy*i,miny)])
        vertices.append([min(minx+dx*(j+1),maxx),max(maxy- dy*(i+1),miny)])
        vertices.append([min(minx+dx*j,maxx),max(maxy-dy*(i+1),miny)])
        parts.append(vertices)
        w.poly(parts)
        w.record(id)

w.save('polygon_grid')
```

Comment: This will not yield a raster but a vector file